# How create an edge of a circular arc with div and css?

Tags: html, css

I try to create an element like this one:

[image]

I can't create a piece of arc of a circle according to a diameter, by playing with the edge of the angles, it doesn't look how I wish.
My result:https://codepen.io/yoan-dev/pen/rNJNPPN

```css
.main {
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 80px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 80px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="main"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: We are not here to do your homework, please add the code of what you already tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: You are right, sorry I update with a codepen

Comment: Why not just use an SVG for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with  `border-top`.

```css
.main {
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 80px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100% 80px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="main"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by styling pseudo element `:before` or `:after`.

Here's the final result:

```css
.main {
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.main::before{
  content: '';
  width: 120%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="main"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand what border-top-left-radius and border-top-right-radius do. There is a good representation on this picture.

[image]

So if you match your height and the second value of those two properties, you will get the effect you are looking for.

```css
.main {
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="main"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: actually since his reference circle is wider than the portion visible he should try with a value at least 2x greater than element's width I think

Comment: the lower the first value (the width) of border-top-left/right-radius property is the bigger the slope will be.